# How to kill a running scheduled task?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have scheduled a task on Windows Server 2008 R2 Task Scheduler that kicks off a python script. However, when the task is running, I don't see the process spawned in the Task Manager and therefore am unable to kill the task.

I know the task was running because it was producing the output files and the output files were locked but there was no related process in the Task Manager! 
How can I kill a running Task Scheduler task?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into Task Scheduler (taskschd.msc).  While there, there's a button on the right menu for Display All Running Tasks.  I think this is what you want.

While you're there, you should turn on Enable All Tasks History, so you could track something like this better in the future.[image]

Comment: Display All Running Tasks and terminating task there seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @jski, Is there a cmd way to do that?